# How do you use the commandline test runner for Dart?

Tags: dart

I've been looking around and can not find any documentation on this. There is supposed to be a command line test runner for Dart.

https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=4226

Answer (score 1):

Are you thinking about a tool used for testing the Dart SDK, or a tool for running your own tests?

In case of the former, there is a testing tool at `./build/test.py`. To eg. run standalone tests for the Dart VM, use `./tools/test.py --mode release --arch ia32 --runtime vm standalone`. You can read more about this at https://code.google.com/p/dart/wiki/TestingDart2js.

In case of the latter, check out http://pub.dartlang.org for community packages. A search for 'test' on the page reveals a few different approaches to testing Dart.

Answer (score 0):

Not a specific answer your question, but I haven't seen any libraries using this command line test runner yet - so it may be best to wait till that is documented, and announced.

In the meantime you can write a small script like below, and call it test.sh (Or bat on Windows). This appears to be the common practice in libraries/apps that I've seen.

```
dartanalyzer lib/mylib.dart
dart --checked test/mylib_test.dart
```

If your tests are split across multiple files you can add each of these files to the script.

If you want to run only a limited set of tests, [see here](http://www.dartlang.org/articles/dart-unit-tests/#running-a-limited-set-of-tests). It is possible to add some code to you test to filter tests based on a regexp search passed in on the command line.

If you're still keen to use this you can get the source code here: [testrunner.dart](https://github.com/dart-lang/bleeding_edge/blob/master/dart/utils/testrunner/testrunner.dart). See the documentation at the top of the file. Perhaps you could file an issue to ask the dart team to publish this on pub. However pub doesn't support publishing executable tools yet - so that will take a while.